# Combos dependientes usando jquery y Codeigniter4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, codeigniter-4

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en Codeigniter4. Tengo un formulario para cargar los proyectos. Dentro de ese formulario tengo dos comboBox dependientes, el primero es el origen que puede ser interno (I) o externo (E), luego el origen se carga el segundo combobox que son los usuarios. El problema que tengo es que me trae bien los usuarios segun el origen pero no entiendo como mostrarlos y cargarlos en el segundo comboBox.
El controlador es ProyectoController:

```
public function getSolicitantes(){
 $id = $this->request->getPost('id');
    $iddepto=13;
    if($this->request->isAJAX()) {
        if($id){
            if($id=='I'){
                $query="select id_solicitante, apellido_nombre from solicitantes where id_departamento=".$iddepto;
            }else{
                $query="select id_solicitante, apellido_nombre from solicitantes where id_departamento<>".$iddepto;
            }
            $sql= $this->db->query($query);
            $result=$sql->getResultArray();
            /*
            foreach ($result as $value)
                $html[]=['id'=>$value['id_solicitante'],'nombre'=>$value['apellido_nombre']];*/
            var_dump($result);
            echo json_encode($result);
           
        }
    }
    else
        echo "hola";
}
```

La vista crear_proyecto.php que muestra el formulario de carga:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group mb-3">
  <label class="form-label">Origen:</label>
  <select name="sele_origen" id="sele_origen" class="form-control form-select-lg mb-3">
     <option selected>---</option>
     <option value="I" <?php if(old('origen')=='I'):?> selected <?php endif;?>>Interno</option>
     <option value="E" <?php if(old('origen')=='E'):?> selected <?php endif;?>>Externo</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <p class="is-danger help"><?=session('errores.origen');?></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" >Solicitante: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <select id="sele_solicitante" class="form-control form-select-lg mb-3"></select> 
 </div>
 <p class="is-danger help"><?=session('errores.sele_solicitante');?></p>
</div>
</div>
```

El javascript que recibe los resultados de la consulta es: Es acá donde no encuentro el modo de mostrar los datos en el comboBox solicitantes

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#sele_origen").change(function(){
      var id=$("#sele_origen").val();
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        //dataType: 'json',
        url:'http://localhost/demopreserva/proyectos/solicitantes',
        data:{id : id},
       
        success:  function (data) {         
          console.log('valor origen'+ id);
          alert(data);
          console.log(data);
          alert(data[0][{"id_solicitante"}]+'hola');
          var html='<option value="">Select Staff</option>';
          for (var count=0;count<data.length;count++){
            html +='<option value"'+data[count].id_solicitante+'">'+data[count].apellido_nombre+'</option';
          }
          $('#sele_solicitante').html(html);
       
        },
        error:function(){
          alert("error")
        }
      })
    })
  })
</script>

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias
```